# joomla extension about product specifications

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Does anybody know what component/module/plugin for **joomla** that i can use to define my criteria for a product specification as my content.

For example, if I would like to have a website discuss on laptop. For laptop specifications,

I would like to define:

about: -description need rich texts

technical specifications: description need rich texts

Processor: description need rich texts

Anybody know how can I do it?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic (this is not a programming question). Please support the [Joomla proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers) on area51 if you'd like a dedicated Joomla equivalent of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the K2 extension:

http://getk2.org

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the specifications to an article?